# File path in VBA code appears to break on macOS

Tags: excel, vba, macos, ms-word, export

I have the following piece of VBA code which exports a number of shapes and tables to a new Word document. It runs perfectly on my Windows PC, but gives a run-time error on Mac. If I run it line by line on the Mac, it seems to break at the Set excelWorkbook = excelApp.Workbooks.Open(FileName) line, which makes me think it has something to do with the file path. The Path variable is a named range in the workbook which has the following formula (=SUBSTITUTE(LEFT(CELL("filename"),SEARCH("]",CELL("filename"))-1),"[",""))

```
Option Explicit

Sub Export()

 ' Declare variables
    Dim excelApp As Object
    Dim excelWorkbook As Object
    Dim excelWorksheet As Object
    Dim wordApp As Object
    Dim wordDoc As Object
    Dim tbl As Object
    Dim FileName As String
    Dim pasteRange As Object
    
    ' Create a new instance of Excel
    Set excelApp = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
    
    ' Open the Excel workbook and worksheet
    
    If InStr(1, Application.OperatingSystem, "Windows") > 0 Then
        ' Windows file path
        FileName = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Questionnaire").Range("Path").Value
    Else
        ' macOS file path
        FileName = Replace(ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Questionnaire").Range("Path").Value, "\", "/")
    End If
    
    Set excelWorkbook = excelApp.Workbooks.Open(FileName) ' Replace with the path to your Excel file
    Set excelWorksheet = excelWorkbook.Sheets("Questionnaire")
        
    ' Create a new instance of Word
    Set wordApp = CreateObject("Word.Application")
    wordApp.Visible = True ' Set to True if you want to see Word
    
    ' Create a new Word document
    Set wordDoc = wordApp.Documents.Add
    
    ' Copy the Excel table and paste it into Word
    'excelWorksheet.Range("Table1").Copy'

   ' wordDoc.Range.PasteExcelTable LinkedToExcel:=False, WordFormatting:=False, RTF:=False'

    
        Set excelWorksheet = excelWorkbook.Sheets("Results")
        
        excelWorksheet.Shapes("Group 2297").Copy
        'wordDoc.Application.Selection.InsertNewPage
        wordDoc.Application.Selection.PasteSpecial DataType:=3
        wordApp.Selection.Collapse Direction:=0

        excelWorksheet.Shapes("Group 2363").Copy
        wordDoc.Application.Selection.InsertNewPage
        wordDoc.Application.Selection.PasteSpecial DataType:=3
        wordApp.Selection.Collapse Direction:=0
        
        excelWorksheet.Shapes("Group 2382").Copy
        wordDoc.Application.Selection.InsertNewPage
        wordDoc.Application.Selection.PasteSpecial DataType:=3
        wordApp.Selection.Collapse Direction:=0
        
        excelWorksheet.Shapes("Group 2400").Copy
        wordDoc.Application.Selection.InsertNewPage
        wordDoc.Application.Selection.PasteSpecial DataType:=3
        wordApp.Selection.Collapse Direction:=0
        
        excelWorksheet.Shapes("Group 2414").Copy
        wordDoc.Application.Selection.InsertNewPage
        wordDoc.Application.Selection.PasteSpecial DataType:=3
        wordApp.Selection.Collapse Direction:=0

    Set excelWorksheet = excelWorkbook.Sheets("Questionnaire")
    
    excelWorksheet.Range("Table1").Copy
    wordDoc.Application.Selection.Find.Execute ""
    wordApp.Selection.PasteExcelTable LinkedToExcel:=False, WordFormatting:=False, RTF:=False '
    
    
    excelWorksheet.Range("Table2").Copy
    wordDoc.Application.Selection.Find.Execute ""
    wordApp.Selection.PasteExcelTable LinkedToExcel:=False, WordFormatting:=False, RTF:=False '
    
    excelWorksheet.Range("Table3").Copy
    wordDoc.Application.Selection.Find.Execute ""
    wordApp.Selection.PasteExcelTable LinkedToExcel:=False, WordFormatting:=False, RTF:=False '
    
    excelWorksheet.Range("Table4").Copy
    wordDoc.Application.Selection.Find.Execute ""
    wordApp.Selection.PasteExcelTable LinkedToExcel:=False, WordFormatting:=False, RTF:=False
    
    
    ' wordDoc.PageSetup.Orientation = 1
    
    ' Clean up
   ' Set tbl = wordDoc.Tables(1)'
    
    ' Additional formatting if needed (optional)
    ' e.g., tbl.Style = "Table Grid"
    
    ' Save the Word document (optional)
    ' wordDoc.SaveAs "C:\Path\To\Your\Word\File.docx"
    
    ' Close Excel without saving changes (optional)
    excelWorkbook.Close False
    
    ' Release objects from memory
    Set tbl = Nothing
    Set wordDoc = Nothing
    Set wordApp = Nothing
    Set excelWorksheet = Nothing
    Set excelWorkbook = Nothing
    Set excelApp = Nothing

End Sub
```

I have tried to implement code that replaces the back slashes with forward slashes on Mac, but this did not resolve the problem.

Comment: Whats the value of _Filename_ when the error occurs?

Comment: I think Office is sandboxed on macOS and is only able to access a limited part of the file system. For any files outside of that limited space it is necessary to use Apple Script.

Comment: Here is Ron de Bruin's page on working around Apple's sandbox requirements: https://macexcel.com/examples/setupinfo/sandbox/